# Instagram Hashtag Search API returns error message "user_id is required" although I have provided it

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to get data about media from my IG Business account with a specific hashtag.
I used Graph API Explorer and tried with

`/{hashtag_id}?user_id={instagram_business_id}&fields=recent_media`

but I got an error "(#100) The parameter user_id is required."

Does anybody know what may be the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API URL is incorrect, your URL should look like this:

```
/{hashtag_id}/recent_media?user_id={instagram_business_id}&fields=id,caption,media_url...
```

Comment: How can I limit this recent_media?